# Float representation, integer bits and fraction bits

Tags: mysql, floating-point

How 8 integer bits and 2 fraction bits, i.e. 00011001 and 10 means 25.75? Considering 2s complement format encoding.

Where do I have to begin in order to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Decimals in Binary work in a similar way to they do in the Decimal, Octal or Hexadecimal, (or any) number system in that each number after the decimal point (or Binary/Octal/Hexadecimal point) carries its own value.

In decimal, we say that the first digit to the right of the decimal point is worth 1/10th, (or 1x10^-1) and the second is worth 1/100th (or 1x10^-2).

In binary, instead of working with 10's it works with 2's, so the first digit after the binary point is worth 1/2 (or 1x2^-1) and the second is worth 1/4 (also written as 1x2^-2), with the exponent decreasing by one for each 'column' to the right of the point.

To convert your example, the first basic step is to calculate the column values, then we simply add up each of the values where a 1 is present in the original binary number (I've added a few extra digits to the example to help explain):

```
 Binary:     1    1    0    0    1    .    1     0      0       0     
 Value:     16    8    4    2    1    .    0.5   0.25   0.175   0.0625
          - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
             |    |    x    x    |    .    |     x      x       x
 Decimal:   16  + 8  +   +    +  1    . +  0.5 +     +      +
```

So the binary number 11001.10 = 25.5 in decimal

Your Question was unfortunately a little unclear so I hope that this is the answer you were looking for, if not, please add some further clarity to your question.

Comment: I really like your answer Ben. Thanks! Now, if I'm in MySQL, having the integer bits in one Byte and the frac bits in another Byte of a BLOB field. I get the int part with CONVERT(HEX(int_part), SIGNED) and what about the frac part?